# More contributions to (make/making?) up

Tags: exam-questions

> In response to the growing crisis, the agency is urgently asking for more contributions to _____ up for its sharp decline in purchasing power.

Which out of *make* and *making* is correct to use here ? I understand with prepositions I need to use *ing* form like *I look forward to meeting you* but I don't know if the *to* in question sentence is preposition or not. Also  let me know if there are any other grammatical errors in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The word *make* is correct.

> In response to the growing crisis, the agency is urgently asking for
>   more contributions to make up for its sharp decline in purchasing
>   power.

Your other example

> I look forward to meeting you

does not use *to* in the same way. In the first case it part of the reason

> asking for more contributions / to make up for

but in the second it is part of the first verb

> I look forward to / meeting you.